# Sphinx xmlpipe2 not indexing indexable fields

Tags: xml, sphinx

I've written a script to pull data from MongoDB and output seemingly valid XML for sphinx, modeled on the example files in the sphinx distribution. The issue I'm having is that none of the fields are actually being indexed, despite everything appearing as though they should.

This is my config: pastebin.com/p5vMXMZw
This is my (truncated) data: pastebin.com/xELB3Ccc

I'm really at a loss as to what I could have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Sphinx Bug.

Answer (score 0):

its a sphinx bug.